# Use class name from properties file as default for factory return

Tags: java

I'm new to class name instantiation from properties files. Never done that before :) 
So, I hava a properties file where to define a class to be used as framework default. For this class, lots of instances should be created through a factory. 
Whats the best factory implementation to use? I came up through research on Google with the Factory Method and the Static Factory Method pattern.

At this point, I do have:

```
public interface Handler { ... }

public class ConcreteHandler1 implements Handler { ... }

public class ConcreteHandler2 implements Handler { ... }
```

From the properties file I need to be able to specify:

> default.handler=com.handlers.ConcreteHandler1

The new specified default handler will be instantiated very often to do its job. Following this template so far:

```
public class HandlerFactory {
    private static Handler defaultHandler = <way to instantiate default handler from properties>

    public Handler getDefaultHandler() {
         return HandlerFactory.defaultHandler;
    }

    public void setDefaultHandler(Handler default) {
         HandlerFactory.defaultHandler = default;
    }
}
```

And the main():

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Handler defHandler = HandlerFactory.getDefaultHandler();
    // Do something with defHandler
    // ...
}
```

How do I implement this in a good and well designed way?

Comment: Load properties files into `Properties` class. Then you can access the class name via the key of the properties file, i.e. `default.handler` using `prop.getProperty("default.handler")`. Then, use reflection to instantiate the class, `Class.forName(clsName).newInstance()`.

Comment: You'll probably want to instantiate the default handler in the getDefaultHandler() instead of the static attribute declaration

Comment: Thanks so far. Instantiation in the getDefaultHandler() would be nice, because of having multiple instances which are needed. However, would this lead to performance minus when creating new instance with newInstance() method (because its reflection)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a simple factory and the objects can be created simply by default constructor, I think `Class.forName(clazzName).newInstance()` is good enough to handle it.

If you have multiple classes and complex parameters and potentially, ordering in constructing them, then I'd recommend some IoC tools like Spring.

Answer (score 0):

obviously, you want your default.handler is configurable and switchable, so, I think your design is so far so good. but one thing you should note: this is just: 'Static Factory Method' pattern, it's no relative to 'Factory Method' pattern. for that pattern, you will design a factory hierarchy to create a product hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution using Google Guice :

```
import com.google.inject.*;
import com.google.inject.name.Named;
import com.google.inject.name.Names;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Properties;

interface Handler
{
}

class ConcreteHandler1 implements Handler
{
}

class ConcreteHandler2 implements Handler
{
}

class HandlerProvider implements Provider<Handler>
{
    private final String className;

    @Inject
    public
    HandlerProvider(@Named("default.handler") String className)
    {
        this.className = className;
    }

    @Override
    public
    Handler get()
    {
        if (className.equals(ConcreteHandler1.class.getName()))
        {
            return new ConcreteHandler1();
        }
        else if (className.equals(ConcreteHandler2.class.getName()))
        {
            return new ConcreteHandler2();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public
class Main
{
    public static
    void main(String[] args)
    {
        Module handlerModule = new AbstractModule()
        {
            @Override
            protected
            void configure()
            {
                Names.bindProperties(binder(), getProperties());
                bind(Handler.class).toProvider(HandlerProvider.class);
            }
        };

        Handler handler = Guice.createInjector(handlerModule)
                               .getInstance(Handler.class);

        System.out.println(Objects.toString(handler));
    }

    private static
    Properties getProperties()
    {
        Properties myProperties = new Properties();
        myProperties.setProperty("default.handler","ConcreteHandler1");
        return myProperties;
    }
}
```

---

**Note:** this implementation of Provider.get() validates that `default.handler` refers to a known implementation. It may be a good or bad thing depending on the desired behavior.